# gpiod_* vs gpio_* methods in the Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, device-driver, device-tree

Which of the GPIO APIs in Linux device driver programming is preferable and  in what conditions: `gpio_set_value()` or `gpiod_set_value()`?

One takes the GPIO desc as the object while other takes the GPIO parsed from the device tree.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For all new drivers it's recommended to use `gpiod_*` API. Old `gpio_*` API is considered deprecated now.

From [this](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=79a9becda8940deb2274b5aa4577c86d52ee7ecb) commit:

> **gpiolib: export descriptor-based GPIO interface**
>
> This patch exports the `gpiod_*` family of API functions, a safer
>   alternative to the legacy GPIO interface. Differences between the gpiod
>   and legacy gpio APIs are:
>
> - gpio works with integers, whereas gpiod operates on opaque handlers
>     which cannot be forged or used before proper acquisition
> - gpiod get/set functions are aware of the active low state of a GPIO
> - gpio consumers should now include `<linux/gpio/consumer.h>` to access
>     the new interface, whereas chips drivers will use
>     `<linux/gpio/driver.h>`
>
> The legacy gpio API is now built as inline functions on top of gpiod.

See next links for details on new gpiod API:

- [[LWN article] GPIO in the kernel: future directions](https://lwn.net/Articles/533632/)
- [[Kernel documentation] GPIO Descriptor Consumer Interface](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/gpio/consumer.html)

  (and rest of gpiod kernel documentation added by [this](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=fd8e198cfcaa8abcc7f7525619d447f9a805e86e) commit)